# Is there an option for batch tagging s3 object in AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tags

I know how to tag single s3 object from my java app. But how can i tag multiple objects at once, if i pass multiple keys ?

We are talking about a big chunk of keys. ~200k

```
List<Tag> newTags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
           newTags.add(new Tag("Tag for delete", "This object should be deleted"));
           amazonS3Client.setObjectTagging(new SetObjectTaggingRequest(bucketName, key, new ObjectTagging(newTags)));
```

I am using the above code for single object tagging.

Comment: do you have an array in which you have access to all the keys in which you want to add your tags ?

Comment: if yes than you can simply have a loop around your code processing each key at each iteration or Am i not able to understand your question correctly let me know

Comment: Yes i can iterate the keys, but lets say if we have 20k keys. It will call s3 20 k times I want to skip this.

Comment: aws released s3 batch operations api, but i think its still in preview you can signup for preview to get an early access https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/s3-batch-operations/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an option for batch tagging s3 objects in AWS.

Since you are asking for a way to do this, I recommend the s3 batch operations feature: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-batch-operations/

You can create a manifest of s3 keys and provide the desired tags in the create job request, and it will tag all of the keys in the manifest with those tags.